# angularjs session storage displaying array data from list of arrays

Tags: java, android, html, angularjs, arraylist

when ever i click on a button the data will pushed in array list and will be stored in the session storage

```
var data = [
             'name':"name",
              'id'=1
             ];
var arrayList = new array;
arrayList.push(data);
sessionStorage.setItems("arrayList",arrayList);
```

I am storing the array list in sessionStorage.
Now I am getting the arrayList from the storage

```
var retrieveArray = sessionStorage.arrayList;
```

Now I want to iterate the arrayList and get the name and id of each product
how can i get the values

Comment: `angular.forEach(retrieveArray, function(data){})`

Comment: hi jonathan, i am getting undefined when i print the (data.name).

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate the retrieved array using a iterator like,

```
 angular.forEach(retrieveArray, function(item){
     var id =item.id;
     var name=item.name;
});
```

you will get the id and name for any item you want by this.